# LaTeX | Section title too long for header and \sectionmark not working on same page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec, section-titles

I am a LaTeX noob but I have not found a solution for this problem yet:

I have a section title (doc class book) too long for the header and I have used the `\sectionmark` solution found here on stackexchange.

```
\section[long title]{long title % 
\sectionmark{short title 1}}
\sectionmark{short title 2}
```

The problem is that the `\sectionmark{short title 2}` works on the next page while `\sectionmark{short title 1}` does not work on the one where the section starts.

If i put the `\sectionmark` before the `\section` then the number of the header title goes wrong.

I cannot change the title or anything else in the graphics as it is part of a book collection that needs to be homogeneous and also `\usepackage{titlesec}` does not work if I add `[toctitles]` as some suggested in other threads.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (with dummy text), which reproduce your problem. It seems to be `\section[<short text in page headers and ToC>]{<a very long, long, long text at section>}`. If you have several `\section` commands in on  a page, in headers will appear only short text from the first command, other text will follow on the next command.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual setup the first sectionmark of the page will be put in the header. So in your case this will be the long title, and "short title 1" will never be used. Later pages will inherit "short title 2" from the previous page.

In the `fancyhdr` version 4.1 documentation, section 33.2 Using explicit marks the following suggestion is given:

```
\section[Long title]{Long title\sectionmark{Short title}}
\sectionmark{Short title}
```

Read that part of the documentation to get some suggestions for macros to make this easier to use if you have more than one of these sections.